# Data binding library when camel case package name

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I am developing a new version of an android app which has been published in the market by some previous developers with a package name like com.mycompany.MyApp and I have to use the same package name.

In my project, I have used The Data Binding Library which needs lowercase notation for package names and I have been receiving "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.mycompany.MyApp.databinding.MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding"

And then according to the official documentation and also some entries in SO, 
I have placed

```
<data class="com.mycompany.MyApp.databinding.MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding" ></data>
```

definition on top of layout in my_fragment_recycler_view_item.xml

Now I can import the class MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding in MyRecyclerViewFragment.kt and access the view elements etc. but the project can not be compiled because the auto-generated class  MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBindingImpl can not be compiled.

Gradle gives "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.mycompany.MyApp.databinding.MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBindingImpl"
and I can see the error in MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBindingImpl class as "Cannot inherit from final 'com.mycompany.MyApp.MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding'"

I guess this is because in Kotlin all the classes are default final but I am stuck here anyway. Is there anything you can suggest or can you see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for all of the reads, comments, and answers.
I can not share the code directly but symbolic codes are like as follows;

MyRecyclerViewFragment.kt

```
import com.mycompany.MyApp.databinding.MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding

class MyRecyclerViewFragment: Fragment()
{
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val fragmentIntroSlidePage = MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding.inflate(inflater,
            container, false)
        //TODO ..
        return fragmentIntroSlidePage.root
    }
}
```

my_fragment_recycler_view_item.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data class="com.mycompany.MyApp.databinding.MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding">

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/myBgColor"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slide_bg_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/intro_slide_1_text"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/intro_slide_01"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="150dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

auto-generated class

```
package com.mycompany.MyApp.databinding;

public class MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBindingImpl extends MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding  {
...
```

Comment: You can change dir name of `MyApp` to whatever you want, just make sure that you don't change applicationId from **Manifest file** or from **Gradle**. Usually, it's best practice to have both package name and application id to be Idle but it's in no harm if you don't follow that rule.

Comment: Changing the package name part worked well. Thank you so much. For future readers let me clarify the solution. When we are adding a custom class definition by using <data class="com.mycompany.MyApp.databinding.MyClassBinding"/> tag in our fragment.xml we don't have to use the same package name as our project. We may give a custom package name. <data class="com.mycompany.binders.databinding.MyClassBinding"/>

Comment: If you don't mind giving it as an answer, I will approve it. Thanks again.

Comment: One possible gotcha here is if the users already have an app shortcut to the main activity in the launcher, it will become broken if the activity's package name changes.

Comment: I didn't change any of the activity package name I have just change the auto generated binder classes target package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.mycompany.MyApp.databinding.MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBindingImpl"
```

Basically this exception states that one can't simply use capitalised name *(Camel Hump case)* in package names for objects passing through data variable in data-binding.

So solution is to making package name in lower case to get rid of the issue. For the case of O.P. it would be solved by renaming `MyApp` to `myapp` or something convenient.

Hence final result would be:

```
<data class="com.mycompany.myapp.databinding.MyFragmentRecyclerViewItemBinding">
```